# Adding names to a scrolling SVG curve

Tags: jquery, svg, scroll

I am trying to create a list of names that scroll along a curve as the user scrolls down. This uses jquery to link the offset position of the text along the svg path with the scroll height. Currently every time I add a name I have to adjust the number (which is currently 70) in the jquery to scroll all the names into view and then stop just as the last name comes into view and no further. So for example with the number of names on there now, if I adjust it down to 60 it wont scroll far enough to show all of them and if I adjust it too high the names scroll too far along the curve which I don't want to happen. I don't know what the correlation (if any) is between this number and the number of names or characters.

Is there anyway that I can use the jquery to detect the number of names or characters and adjust  dynamically to always scroll the names just far enough into view, so i don't have to always manually adjust the jquery every time a name is added to the list.

Here is the example

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#text-path");

const h = document.documentElement, 
      b = document.body,
      st = 'scrollTop',
      sh = 'scrollHeight';

document.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
  let percent = (h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 70;
  textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", (-percent * 40) + 20)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 5rem 0;
  min-height: 200vh;
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
}
p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 1rem;
}
text {
  fill: red;
  font-size: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
  <path id="curve" fill="transparent" d="M65.9,222.1c115.6-21.7,281.1-3.9,352.5,102.4c35.7,53.1,44,119.8,25.1,180.3c-20,64.1-64.2,124.1-65,193.1
    c-0.8,65.9,50.5,123.8,111,150c65.9,28.5,150.5,32.9,220.7,20.1c71.3-12.9,141.3-60.9,157.7-131.5c17.4-75-25.1-142.5-65.5-201.5
    c-30.8-44.9-61.6-94.4-59.8-148.8c3-88.4,91.2-146.9,172-154.8c93.9-9.2,230.5,26.9,278.6,115.9c27.1,50.2,22.9,111,14.8,167.4
    c-14.7,102.2-21.8,206.5,66.2,278.8c77.7,63.9,198,63.5,268.3-12.1c53.1-57.1,64.2-145.9,33.5-216c-15.8-36.2-38.5-69-56.2-104.4
    c-10.2-20.3-18.9-42.1-19.1-64.9c-0.6-67.9,62.3-120.1,126.5-127.1c59.5-6.5,140.4,28.6,204,56.6"></path>
  <text dy="31" width="100%" height="100%" style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0);">
      <textPath style="transform:translate3d(0,0,0);" alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#curve" startOffset="20px" id="text-path">JAMES DYER AL MURPHY CHRISSIE ABBOTT CECILE DORMEAU GRACE HELMER OWEN POMERY SUPER FREAK JASON LYON DANIEL FROST ESSY MAY JACK HUDSON KATE ISOBEL SCOTT </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/dan-hayman/pen/VweZKdp

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is this:

you need the length of the path and you can get it using `curve.getTotalLength();`.

You also need the length of the text. next you get the difference (delta in my code) between the 2 lengths and you use this value to reset the value of the attribute `startOffset`

**problem 1:**
You can't get the right value if you try to get the length of `theText` - the one with the textPath. You need to put the text in a different text element (`#txt` in my code) and get the length of this text. Next I use `textPath.textContent` to set the text content of the text path element.

**problem 2:**
In order to get the length of the text, normally I would use `txt.getComputedTextLength()` or `txt.textLength.baseVal.value;` but since in the css you have `letter-spacing: 5px;` none of these will return the correct value. So I'm using `const textLength = txt.getBBox().width;`

```js
const textPath = document.querySelector("#text-path");
const txt = document.querySelector("#txt");
const curve = document.querySelector("#curve");
//txt.getComputedTextLength()
//txt.textLength.baseVal.value;
const textLength = txt.getBBox().width;
const curveLength = curve.getTotalLength();


textPath.textContent = txt.textContent;

let delta = textLength - curveLength;

const h = document.documentElement, 
      b = document.body,
      st = 'scrollTop',
      sh = 'scrollHeight';

document.addEventListener("scroll", e => {  
  let percent = (h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight);
  let att = -(percent * (delta * 100/curveLength)) + "%";
  textPath.setAttribute("startOffset", att);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 5rem 0;
  min-height: 200vh;
  font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
}

text {
  fill: red;  
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  outline:solid;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 2000 1000">
<defs>
  <path id="curve" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"  d="M65.9,222.1c115.6-21.7,281.1-3.9,352.5,102.4c35.7,53.1,44,119.8,25.1,180.3c-20,64.1-64.2,124.1-65,193.1
    c-0.8,65.9,50.5,123.8,111,150c65.9,28.5,150.5,32.9,220.7,20.1c71.3-12.9,141.3-60.9,157.7-131.5c17.4-75-25.1-142.5-65.5-201.5
    c-30.8-44.9-61.6-94.4-59.8-148.8c3-88.4,91.2-146.9,172-154.8c93.9-9.2,230.5,26.9,278.6,115.9c27.1,50.2,22.9,111,14.8,167.4
    c-14.7,102.2-21.8,206.5,66.2,278.8c77.7,63.9,198,63.5,268.3-12.1c53.1-57.1,64.2-145.9,33.5-216c-15.8-36.2-38.5-69-56.2-104.4
    c-10.2-20.3-18.9-42.1-19.1-64.9c-0.6-67.9,62.3-120.1,126.5-127.1c59.5-6.5,140.4,28.6,204,56.6"></path>
  <text dy="70" id="txt" font-size="70px">JAMES DYER AL MURPHY CHRISSIE ABBOTT CECILE DORMEAU GRACE HELMER OWEN POMERY SUPER FREAK JASON LYON DANIEL FROST ESSY MAY JACK HUDSON KATE ISOBEL SCOTT</text>
  </defs>
  
  <text dy="31" font-size="70" id="theText">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve" id="text-path" startOffset="0"></textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great thanks so much for the response. Looks really promising. Will test it out and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thats works like a charm. Thank you very much. Only one problem seems to be if you refresh the page it starts to scroll too far but navigating to the page it works every time. I'm guessing this has something to do with the scripts loading before or after the html?

Comment: I don't know. Can you link to the page?

Comment: yeah sure its this one. https://brilliantartists.co.uk/dev/artists/

Comment: Very nice, very aesthetic. I don't see any problem. However I would recommend body{overflow:hidden}

Comment: Thanks yeah its definitely more about the aesthetic on this page. Ok so when you refresh the page it still works in the same way? hidden overlay on body stops the scroll then adding overflow scroll on the parent section doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.